# How to solve an equation with a function in it?

Tags: functions

How to solve an equation with a function? For example, let's say a simple case:

$f(kX) = Y$

All the function does is caps the parameter to a maximum of 10.
So that means:

$f(0.05 * 100) = 5$

$f(0.05 * 1000) = 10$

$f(0.05 * 500) = 10$

$f(0.05 * 1) = 0.05$, etc..

I want to solve this for $X$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
Y = \max\{kX,10\}
$$
you can only solving for $X$ if the value of $kX < 10$ then you have some idea of what $X$ will be, namely, $Y = kX$

Answer (score 0):

If $Y \lt 10$, you can solve for $X$ easily.

If $Y = 10$, you can only determine a range of values for $X$.  Since $kX \ge 10$, you would divide by $k$ on both sides to solve for $X$.

This results in the following solution:

If $Y \lt 10$, then $X = {Y\over k}$

If $Y = 10$ and $k$ is positive, then $X \ge {Y\over k}$

If $Y = 10$ and $k$ is negative, then $X \le {Y\over k}$